# Parse Google Bookmark (HTML) into Arrays - JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am building a lite web-app to load bookmarked Items into webviews. I have a 3-Tiered bookmark structure using Google Chrome bookmarks.

```
Tier 1 (Tenant)
Tier 2 (Service)
Tier 3 (Link)
```

From each Tier I would like the following information putting into an array

```
Tier 1 - Description
Tier 2 - Description
Tier 3 - Description & URL
```

What would be the best way for me to be able to parse this file, and build an array of the information I want.

In pseudo code I have something like this, however I am struggling to apply this using any language I know. I was told PHP would be the best way to go but if possible I would like to keep this client side. So JavaScript/jQuery would be best.

Any thought/suggestions/alternatives would be most helpful.

```
Description = Array
URL         = Array

$Tier1       = 0;
$Tier2       = 0;
$Tier3       = 0;

$tier        = 0;

Start Read the bookmark file line by line

      if <DL>  then
      {
          $tier = $tier + 1;           

          If $tier = 1
          {
              $Tier1 = $Tier1 + 1;
              $Tier2 = 1;
              $Tier3 = 1;
          }

          If $tier = 2
          {
              $Tier2 = $Tier2 + 1;
              $Tier3 = 0;
          }

          If $tier = 3
          {
              $Tier3 = 1;
          }                
      }   

      if </DL>  then
      {
          $tier = $tier - 1;

          if $tier = 2
          {
              $Tier3 = 1;
          }

          if $tier = 1
          {
              $Tier2 = 1;
              $Tier3 = 1;
          }

          if $tier = 0
          {
              $Tier1 = 1;
              $Tier2 = 1;
              $Tier3 = 1;
          }
      }   

      if <H3> 
      {
          Description [$Tier1] [$Tier2] [$Tier3]   =  text from html;
          URL [$Tier1] [$Tier2] [$Tier3]   =  "";           
      }

      if <A> 
      {
          Description [$Tier1] [$Tier2] [$Tier3]   =  text from html;
          URL [$Tier1] [$Tier2] [$Tier3]   =  url from html"";          
      }

End of Read loop
```

Example Chrome Bookmark (HTML)

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>Bookmarks</H1>
<DL><p>
    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1444728233" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547034" PERSONAL_TOOLBAR_FOLDER="true">Bookmarks bar</H3>
    <DL><p>

        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495544136" LAST_MODIFIED="1495544331">Test Folder 1 (Tier 1)</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495544331" LAST_MODIFIED="1495546321">Test 1 (Tier 2)</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495546129" LAST_MODIFIED="1495546445">Test 1 (Tier 3)</H3>
                <DL><p>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://stackoverflow.com/" ADD_DATE="1495546321" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Stack Overflow</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://dirtymarkup.com/" ADD_DATE="1495546340" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">DirtyMarkup · Tidy up your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="http://www.bbc.com/news" ADD_DATE="1495546445" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAT0lEQVQ4je2RMQ7AIAwDz/z/z+5QgajJUmXlxkO2kQIXAe7kB4Bt7G9P5So/VpV0BNLZRhKSzoL5mGvpkl8/qNA75BXY19MVXu0rNLKXyQMkVzL9n5I6iQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">Home - BBC News</A>
                </DL><p>
            </DL><p>
        </DL><p>
        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495546969" LAST_MODIFIED="1495546987">Test Folder 2 (Tier 1)</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495546987" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547012">Test 2 (Tier 2)</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495547012" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547167">Test 2 (Tier 3)</H3>
                <DL><p>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://stackoverflow.com/" ADD_DATE="1495547167" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Stack Overflow</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://dirtymarkup.com/" ADD_DATE="1495547167" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">DirtyMarkup · Tidy up your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="http://www.bbc.com/news" ADD_DATE="1495547167" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAT0lEQVQ4je2RMQ7AIAwDz/z/z+5QgajJUmXlxkO2kQIXAe7kB4Bt7G9P5So/VpV0BNLZRhKSzoL5mGvpkl8/qNA75BXY19MVXu0rNLKXyQMkVzL9n5I6iQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">Home - BBC News</A>
                </DL><p>
            </DL><p>
        </DL><p>
        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495547034" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547056">Test Folder 3 (Tier 1)</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495547056" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547084">Test 3 (Tier 2)</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495547084" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547171">Test 3 (Tier 3)</H3>
                <DL><p>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://stackoverflow.com/" ADD_DATE="1495547171" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Stack Overflow</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://dirtymarkup.com/" ADD_DATE="1495547171" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">DirtyMarkup · Tidy up your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="http://www.bbc.com/news" ADD_DATE="1495547171" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAT0lEQVQ4je2RMQ7AIAwDz/z/z+5QgajJUmXlxkO2kQIXAe7kB4Bt7G9P5So/VpV0BNLZRhKSzoL5mGvpkl8/qNA75BXY19MVXu0rNLKXyQMkVzL9n5I6iQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">Home - BBC News</A>
                </DL><p>
            </DL><p>
        </DL><p>
    </DL><p>
</DL><p>
```

Comment: You might be able to use http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php to load the file as html, and traverse it.

Comment: If possible I want to stay away from PHP. Although as a last resort I will look into this. Thank you